# Change grey color profile to colored one in image

Tags: macos, catalina, preview

I wanted to do some fancy image editing, copy/paste a few other images into one PNG.

To prepare a canvas for myself I did:

```
convert -size 1920x1080 xc:white white.png
```

then I opened the all-white PNG in Preview.app, copied some other wonderfully colored images into it, edited around until I was happy.

I saved the image.

Then I closed Preview.app.

Upon closing Preview.app, the image turned from color to monochrome.

Checking image info reveals:

> Color model: Grey
> ColorSync profile: Calibrated Gray Colorspace

I guess this is an unfortunate effect of the imagemagick command I used (and [I've since learnt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65322802/3310334) that the output file name could have instead been `PNG24:white.png` to generate an sRGB PNG that won't have this problem.)

There's a lot of work I will have to redo now if this is irreversible.

How can I retrieve the colors of the image? (I'm hoping the color information could still be there and reassigning color profile can reveal them)

The menu option Tools > Assign Color Profile... in Preview.app does not show me any non-grayscale color profiles.